# On Gentoo, how can one connect to the WiFi from the command-line without the NetworkManager daemon running?

Tags: wifi, gentoo

I am running a Gentoo system with the runit init system. I can't seem to start NetworkManager as while I've set up a service for it with a run file I copied from Void Linux and enabled it (by running `ln -sf /etc/sv/networkmanager /etc/service`) it doesn't seem to be running (and yes the dbus service is running). I've created a package to provide this NetworkManager service and it is [here](https://github.com/fusion809/fusion809-overlay/tree/master/runit-service/service-networkmanager), in case this issue interests you. By doesn't seem to I mean running `nmtui` returns:

```
NetworkManager is not running.
```

So as a temporary workaround I'm wondering if there is any way to connect to the WiFi without needing the NetworkManager daemon running. Likewise wpa_supplicant doesn't seem to work. As I ran:

```
wpa_supplicant -B -i interface -c <(wpa_passphrase SSID passwd)
dhclient interface
```

Where, of course, SSID is replaced with my SSID and passwd with my interface's password and still `ping www.google.com` returns the classic:

```
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

this last command (`dhclient interface`) took about a minute and a half to complete, while the `wpa_supplicant` command immediately finished.

I have set up the wpa_supplicant daemon to run with:

```
sudo ln -sf /etc/sv/wpa_supplicant /etc/service/
```

where my wpa_supplicant run file I got from Void too. I can confirm that wpa_supplicant was running in the background, as `ps ax | grep wpa` returns:

```
 2651 ?        Ss     0:00 runsv wpa_supplicant
 3192 ?        Ss     0:00 wpa_supplicant -B -i wlo1 -c /proc/self/fd/11
18843 ?        Ss     0:00 wpa_supplicant -B -i wlo1 -c /proc/self/fd/11
22662 ?        Ss     0:00 wpa_supplicant -B -i wlo1 -c /proc/self/fd/11
```

where, of course, wlo1 is my WiFi interface.

Comment: No , Network manager depend on the wpa_supplicant daemon , you can connect through wpa_supplicant.  test it `wpa_supplicant -B -i interface -c <(wpa_passphrase SSID passwd)` then run `dhclient`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect to Wifi on linux system through `wpa_supplicant` , you don't need the network-manager , the `nmtui` is a text user interface for network-manager.

Check if there are a wpa_supplicant already running through `ps` command , make sure to kill process `killall wpa_supplicant` before using the `wpa_supplicant` command.

To temporary connect without creating a configuration file:

```
killall wpa_supplicant
wpa_supplicant -B -i <interface> -c <(wpa_passphrase SSID password)
dhcpcd
```

To connect using a configuration file:

create a `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file with the following content:

```
/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

ctrl_interface=/run/wpa_supplicant
update_config=1
```

To configure some access point use:

```
wpa_passphrase SSID password >> /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Connect:

```
killall wpa_supplicant
wpa_supplicant -B -i <interface> -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
dhcpcd
```

Also you can use the `wpa_cli` tool to manage and connect through the cli.

Gentoo wiki : [wpa_supplicant](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Wpa_supplicant)

Comment: Tried it unfortunately it doesn't work for me. Running `ping www.google.com` returns the classic unable to resolve host error.

Comment: @BH2017 maybe your are missing the configuration of dhcpcd and the net script mentioned on the Gentoo wiki.

Comment: @BH2017 Do not forget to kill the runing process of `wpa_supplicant` : `killall wpa_supplicant`

Comment: The Wiki says, "All dhcpcd configuration can be set in the /etc/dhcpcd.conf file, but for most installations dhcpcd will work out of the box presuming most computers nowadays are behind a router or access point running a DHCP server." So shouldn't I need no config file? How do I set up the config file? Should I use what's mentioned with "Static IP addresses", I don't know my IP, how do I determine it? I saw https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/linux-get-ip-address/ but ifconfig isn't present on my Gentoo system. The article is old so I'm wondering if it's because it's deprecated.

Comment: @BH2017 the net-tools is depricated you should use the iproute2 commands (`ip a` command replace `ifconfig`) , undo the created symlinks until you get the wifi working

Comment: I managed to fix it by removing /etc/service/wpa_supplicant and running the "To connect using a configuration file" part of your answer. I'd recommend bolding that line as it's what the rest of your answer pertains to right?

Comment: @BH2017 the first part should work after `killall wpa_supplicant` , can you test it?

Comment: Gave it a go and assuming doing the "To connect using a configuration file" stuff earlier wouldn't obscure the result of rebooting and doing the first part it worked. I'd suggest you mention the possible need to run `killall wpa_supplicant` in your answer.